# Mobile browser webworker & offline storage support

Tags: android, ios, html, mobile, web-worker

Does any mobile browser (Android, ios) support Webworker and offline storage?

Is there any restriction when compared to desktop browsers (Size, resource etc)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Opera Mini for Android supports Webworkers. Safari on iPhone (4.2) and Android web browser don't support Web Workers. I am sure Opera for iPhone would definitely provide support, though I haven't tested it.

Comment: Opera Mini does not support Webworkers: http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/productspecs/

Answer (score 0):

caniuse.com is the best place to look for anwsers to that.

Mobile browsers have a limit of cache of 50Mb